# Glitch on hover and visited selector on transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

When I define a color for `:visited` it seems to go back to the parent's color first before applying the color for the `:hover` style:

```
body {
    color:black;
}
a {
    color:inherit;
    -webkit-transition:ease 3s;
}
a:visited {
    color:pink;
}
a:hover, a:visited:hover {
    color:yellow;
}​
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuqXP/1/)

Is there a hack/fix for this?

Comment: I can't replicate the issue in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This is because [Firefox does not allow certain styles on :visited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Privacy_and_the_%3avisited_selector), for privacy reasons.